# Android Keyboard input predefined text

Tags: android, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, android-softkeyboard, custom-keyboard

I have been following [this tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-custom-keyboard-on-android--cms-22615) on making a custom keyboard. So far so good.

However, I wanted to know, is it possible to create a button to input predefined text. Eg. A button labeled "Name" which inputs the user's name?
If it is possible, how do I do it? I have done extensive research, but can find nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. In your implementation of InputMethodService define new keycode

```
private final static int NAME_CODE = -32; // value is absolutely random. The main requirement - there should not be coincidence with other codes
```

and later check for it in the onKey() method

```
@Override
public void onKey(int primaryCode, int[] keyCodes) {
    InputConnection ic = getCurrentInputConnection();
        switch(primaryCode){
        .....
        case NAME_CODE:
            ic.commitText(name, name.length());
            break;
        .....
```

And after that just use this code to bind special key from your Keyboard specification (qwerty.xml in example) and the logic.

```
<Key android:codes="-32" android:keyLabel="NAME" android:keyWidth="20%p" android:isRepeatable="true"/>
```